# Issues installing react-native on macOS

Tags: react-native

When I'm using `npm install -g react-native-cli` it gives me an error:

[image: error]]

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: try using yarn instead

Comment: can you try to install with sudo npm install react-native-cli?

Comment: Sathvik, it gives me a warnings now, not errors...

Comment: can you please show the warning?

Comment: the problem has been solved, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then you will have to insert your password user, the problem is that you don't have user access if you don't make a `sudo` command before.